# (Solved))The result could not be loaded-jquery-select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I’ve got a problem.

The select box of “Job No.#” can render data from MySQL, but the select box of “Address” cannot.

Field “address” and field “job_number” come from the same table.

But if I create a new field, like “newAddress”, with the same data as in “address”, it works~,

But just changing the “address” to “newAddress” doesn’t work.

In addition to the “address” field, several other fields in this table cannot be rendered either.

The database structure should be ok~ because I am able to fetch() and print the data from the “address” with the same SQL sentence.

And it is working all right on other tables~

Could you please? Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!
The reason is a kind of “-” symbol input by users before.
The "-" is longer than normal -.
json_encode() cannot encode it, and it is displayed as garbled code when I print it out directly.